# Dilution of coffee in a mug placed under the tap

Tags: functions, exponential-function

> A mug filled with coffee sits in the sink. You turn on the faucet and a column of water enters the coffee mug. The mug is already full ($V_0$) at a known concentration of coffee ($C_0$). 
>   I want to figure out how much coffee remains after $X$ amount of water has poured into the mug.

Assume:

1. The coffee isn’t sticking to the sides like crazy.
2. We use metric to make life easier.
3. Every mL of water going into the mug is equal to the number of mL flowing out of the mug.
4. As water is added to the mug, it is instantaneously diluted throughout the mug.

If this were a serial dilution or something similar, this would be straightforward. It is not. Here, the coffee is being diluted as it flows out, so there is a geometric loss of the coffee.

There is no time factor, so no need to worry about flow rate, because we assume instantaneous dilution so that the concentration at any time is just a factor of the water going in and diluted coffee going out.

Now, I've managed to work out how to calculate this. But that isn't a generalized formula, which is what I want.

To calculate after 1 mL is added would be:

$$
C_0-(1/V_0)(C_0)
$$

Subsequent mL would expand the function. For example, the second mL would be

$$
\left(C_0- \frac{C_0}{V_0}\right) - \frac{1}{V_0}\left(C_0- \frac{C_0}{V_0}\right)
$$

And so on and so on. I recognize that it’s not actually $1/V_0$ but $V_{\rm input}/V0$, but that isn’t quite right because it would be a linear dilution then, whereas I’m looking for the moment by moment addition.

It works, but is klunky and awkward and I don’t know how to describe it in a generalized form. I’ve been wracking my brains over this for a week, and I’m either otherthinking something obvious (probably) or am delving into a system more complex than I have the math for (also a distinct possibility). Please help!

> Bonus question: What happens when we no longer assume the water dilutes instantaneously but spreads outward in a circle/column?

Comment: Thank you for the formatting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a constant flow rate $\varrho$ and an instant dilution, the infinitesimal variation of $C$ is ruled by $$C(t+dt)\approx\frac{V_0}{V_0+\varrho dt} C(t)$$ hence $$C'(t)=-\frac{\varrho}{V_0} C(t)$$ which is solved by $$C(t)=C_0e^{-\varrho t/V_0}$$ The time $t_V$ at which the total volume added is $V$ solves $$\varrho t_V=V$$ and then $$C(t_V)=C_0e^{-V/V_0}$$ If the dilution is not instantaneous, more information is needed about the filling and dilution mechanisms.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I had a funny feeling that trying to do the calculations without the time variable included was what was tripping me up. I’m going to run through the calculations a bit to make sure I understand them and it makes sense, and if it works I’ll mark the answer. Btw, silly question but if there a name for this? Seems like there’s always a name for these problems and things.

Comment: "i[s] there a name for this?" Depends on what you mean exactly by "this". The model itself is often called a Malthusian model, by analogy with population models, or an exponential model.

Comment: it works beautifully, thank you so much! And yea, I wanted to read into it a little more, so now I can look into Malthusian models. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Sorry, sanity check here: if I wanted to add an efficiency factor (to account for other fluids, maybe not Coffee maybe it’s honey or chocolate syrup or whatever- it doesn’t automatically suspect 100% in the water) to the final equation, it would be a scaler multiplied by the exponent, right? So a 25% efficiency would be C(tv)=C0e^(-.25V/V0)

Comment: Again, with no precise definition of what you mean by "efficiency factor", it is difficult to say. Knowing the physico-chemical mechanisms at work that you have in mind would be a start...

Comment: good point. I’m talking about where the coffee doesn’t suspend or dissolve well in the water (poor example, I know) so it isn’t just a dilution, the a percentage of the coffee is removed below that of the dilution. Make more sense?